# Getting values of both attribute and element in an xml

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following xml

```
<lists>
   <list Group="3">More_lists_go_here</list>
</lists>
```

What I want is both the `list` element value which is `More_lists_go_here` and the `Group` attribute value which is `3`.

What I have tried so far is

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml("<list Group=\"3\">More_lists_go_here</list>");
XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
string value = root.Descendants("lists").Elements("list").Select(x => (string)x.Attribute("Group")).ToList();
```

what that gets me is

```
value = 3
```

what I want is both `3` and `More_lists_go_here` for string `value`

Comment: Please add a desired output to the question.

Comment: @YitzhakKhabinsky what I want is to access this XML by both the attribute and element value

Answer (score 0):

Use xml linq :

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Xml;
using System.Xml.Linq;

namespace ConsoleApplication40
{
    class Program
    {
        const string FILENAME = @"c:\temp\test.xml";
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string input = "<lists><list Group=\"3\">More_lists_go_here</list></lists>";

            XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(input);
            var results = doc.Descendants("list").Select(x => new { group = (string)x.Attribute("Group"), value = (string)x }).ToList(); 
 
        }
    }
 
}
```

Comment: it gives the CS0746 error `Invalid anonymous type member declarator`

Comment: There is an error in the xml.  From VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  The paste xml into window.  Errors will show up in Error list like compiler errors.